# How can i get my Beautiful soup output data to a text file?

Tags: python, html, file, text, beautifulsoup

I try to export the result of what beautifulsoup extracted from the html code of the web page to a text file but I can not, it writes me € XL in the file. I think it should convert the result into readable text but I do not know how.

Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from urllib.request import urlopen

pageFile = urlopen("exemple of url")
pageHtml = pageFile.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(pageHtml,"html.parser")

myfile.close()

Sdef = soup.findAll('li',class_='exemple_class')

len(Sdef)
Sdef[0].text
Sdef[0].attrs
for t in Sdef:
print(t.text)

with open("output_file","wb") as file:

    import sys
    sys.setrecursionlimit(50000)

    import pickle

    pickle = pickle.Pickler(file)
    pickle.dump(t.text)
```

Comment: Could you share current saved file content?

Comment: In the output file there are : €XL.Q but this is

Comment: but it changes a little according to the times

Comment: Could you include `t.text` in your post?

Comment: When I write t.text, I have : €XL.Q and one or two anothers random characters.